# Elastic search boolean query object array should clause

Tags: elasticsearch, booleanquery

Given doc:
books

```json
[
 {
  name: "book a",
  authors: 
  [
   {
    name: "John",
   }
   {
    name: "Paul"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  name: "book b",
  authors: 
  [
   {
    name: "Paul"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Goal: Return the book which match `name` = `book a` AND match one of the author name with `authors.name` = `John`.

What I tried:

```json
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "name": {
                          "value": "book a"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "authors.name": {
                                "value": "John"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

mapping
name: text
authors: dynamic

Comment: `book a` and `book b` is part of single elasticsearch document or seperate document in elasticsearch index.

Comment: seperate document @SagarPatel

Comment: Can you please put index mapping for your book index.

Comment: @SagarPatel ty for comment, updated with mappings.

Comment: @Shawan I have updated my answer based on mapping you have provided. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query:

Please note that, if you are using dynemic mapping of elasticsearch then used `name.keyword` and `authors.name.keyword`. otherwise use `name` and `authors.name` if you have specified your custom mapping.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "book a"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "authors.name.keyword": {
              "value": "John"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wondering why we need the `.keyword` to make it works? Also, both match and term are in `must` not should?

Comment: You need `.keyword` because term query work with keyword type of field only and it will look for exact match. Also, it is required in `must` because you have mentioned to match as `AND`. If you specify as `should` then atleast on condition match then result will be return.